# JMeter Test Results Monitoring/ Analysis

Tags: apache, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I want to start load testing by running JMeter from command line for more accurate test results, but how can I monitor the run and then analyze the results after the test finishes.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate JTL (JMeter results) file while executing the JMX (JMeter script) file from command line. A sample command for generating JTL file will look like this..

```
jmeter -n -t path-to-jmeterScript.jmx -l path-to-jtlFile.jtl
```

After completion of script execution you can open the JMeter GUI and simply open the JTL file in any listener (as per your requirement).

Answer (score 0):

Most of the listeners in JMeter have an option to save the results into a file. This file contains usually not the report itself, but the samples which are generated by the tests. If you define this filename, you can generate the reports using these saved files. For example see http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report .

Answer (score 0):

If you run JMeter in [command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) passing results file name via `-l` parameter it will output results there. After test finishes you will be able to open the file with the [Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) of your choice and perform the analysis.

By default JMeter writes results in chunks, if you need to monitor them in real time add the following line to *user.properties* file (lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true
```

You can use other properties which names start with `jmeter.save.saveservice.*` to control what metrics you need to store. The list with default values can be seen in *jmeter.properties* file. See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on various JMeter properties types and ways of working with them.

You can also consider running your JMeter test via [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool - it provides some statistics as the test goes either in console mode or via web interface.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot.
About Taurus, does its installation or .jmx test execution work in offline environments?

Comment: What do you mean by offline? You need some network connectivity to produce the load on your application. Internet connection is not mandatory

Comment: The application is located on my local machine (localhost:8080/my-app)

Comment: The application is located on my local machine (localhost:8080/my-app)
and this machine is not connected to the internet.
Taurus support team said that internet connection is needed.

Comment: Installation - you will need Internet access. Once you set this up - Internet connection is not required for running the test via Taurus